# Filtering fields in Multidimensional array, placing them in new array, based on key. [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

For a webstore script I am trying to create a filter for my two dimensional array.
I have used a few guides and other answers here on Stackoverflow or w3Schools, but I keep running into the same problem;

**The newly created array just has empty gaps where the filter takes out the data, rather than creating a 0 to 100 array full of relevant information.**

Since I am still new to the whole multidimensional array thing, I was hoping somebody here could point me in the right direction and tell me what I`m doing wrong.

Array getting fully filled with stuff from my Database

```
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        $product[] = [
                            "ID" => $row["ID"],
                            "Name" => $row["Productname"],
                            "Price" => $row["Pricetag"],
                            "Supply" => $row["Productsupply"],
                            "Type" => $row["Producttype"],
                            "Tags" => $row["Tags"],
                            "Materials" => $row["Materials"],
                            "Date" => $row["Releasedate"],
                            "Description" => $row["Description"],
                            "isDigital" => $row["isDigital"],
                            "MainPhoto" => $row["MainPhoto"],
                            "Photo01" => $row["Productpic01"],
                            "Photo02" => $row["Productpic02"],
                            "Photo03" => $row["Productpic03"]
                        ];
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results found. Please check database connection.";
                }
```

Script to filter this data and creating a new array based on the matches in the key:

```
    $Filterarray = array('Pluimstaart'); //Might filter on more keywords in future usage.
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $finalVal) {
            if(in_array($finalVal, $Filterarray)){ // check if available in filter array
                $newArr[$key]["ID"] = $value["ID"];
                $newArr[$key]["Name"] = $value["Name"];
                $newArr[$key]["Price"] = $value["Price"];
                $newArr[$key]["Supply"] = $value["Supply"];
                $newArr[$key]["Type"] = $value["Type"];
                //$newArr[$key][] = $finalVal;
            }       
        }   
    }
```

Output on website:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [Name] => Pluisje de Pluimstaart
            [Price] => 75
            [Supply] => 0
            [Type] => Pluimstaart
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 69
            [Name] => Blizzard de Pluimstaart
            [Price] => 75
            [Supply] => 1
            [Type] => Pluimstaart
        )
)
```

**The problem here being the skip from 1 to 5, I want the new array to just say**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [Name] => Pluisje de Pluimstaart
                [Price] => 75
                [Supply] => 0
                [Type] => Pluimstaart
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 69
                [Name] => Blizzard de Pluimstaart
                [Price] => 75
                [Supply] => 1
                [Type] => Pluimstaart
            )
    )
```

Comment: use array_values() method in order to get numeric indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use array_values function like this:

```
  $newArr = array(1 => array("one", "two", "three"), 5 => array("horse", "cat", "monkey"));

print_r($newArr); // test print

$newArr = array_values($newArr);

print_r($newArr); // test print
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes the code a lot shorter. With Suriya's answer I got a good idea of how to use it, but this works much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the array function, array_values()

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Thank you very much, echo array_values($newArr)[$j]['Name']; displays the correct names in the correct order now!

Comment: Still at 10 reputation, so my votes arent counted yet, sorry!

Comment: No problem @DanieldeRidder :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a key for each product filtered in your $newArr, this means that you'll get the new array with the original indexes.

To avoid it, just remove the $key index from the $newArr[] initialization.

```
$Filterarray = array('Pluimstaart'); //Might filter on more keywords in future usage.
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $finalVal) {
            if(in_array($finalVal, $Filterarray)){ // check if available in filter array
                $newArr[]["ID"] = $value["ID"];
                $newArr[]["Name"] = $value["Name"];
                $newArr[]["Price"] = $value["Price"];
                $newArr[]["Supply"] = $value["Supply"];
                $newArr[]["Type"] = $value["Type"];
                //$newArr[][] = $finalVal;
            }       
        }   
    }
```

or, even better

```
if(in_array($finalVal, $Filterarray)){
    array_push($newArr, array(
        "ID" => $value["ID"],
        "Name" => $value["Name"],
        "Price" => $value["Price"],
        "Supply" => $value["Supply"],
        "Type" => $value["Type"]
    );
}
```

If you need to keep track of the $key, just store it in an additional $newArr parameter.

Comment: In other words, my code could be a lot shorter and more optimized if I didnt stare down the problems in the foreach loops? haha!

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood part of your code. It works now, thank you very much!